# Postman- Use collection variable in request body

Tags: postman

I have a problem with Postman, where I want to use collection variables inside the request body.
According to postman documentation, all variables in postman GUI can be retrieved with double curly braces {{}}.
But it does not work for me. If I move variables from collection to environment, everything is working OK, but as soon as I move the variable from the environment to collection, it starts throwing errors like this:

```
JSONError: Unexpected token 'U' at 1:1
Unrecognized token 'Backend': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object
```

This is my body:

```
{
    "name": {{BackendValidationPSName}},
    "groups": {{myBackendValidationRGuuids}}
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Tx.

Answer (score 9):

The values have to be in double quotes

```
{
    "name": "{{BackendValidationPSName}}",
    "groups": "{{myBackendValidationRGuuids}}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach also works!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I was missing the "" in the collection variable value.